# Snowflake Extracting Month, year from date

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with a column called created_date that has  date like 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000
and I'm trying to create a column that will show only the year, another one the month
and one that shows the month as a string

here what I try

```
select date_part(year,'created_date ') as year,
       date_part(month, 'created_date ') as month
       to_char(Month, 'created_date') as month_name,
       user_name,
       product
 from user_table
```

Unfortunately when running the query above, I get an error that Function Extract do not support VARCHAR(10) argument type

The result I'm trying to get is to who a table like

```
        year   month month_name   user_name     product
        2021   01     January     John Doe      Ninja Mixer
        2021   05     May         Clide Smith   Blender
```

Any help will be appreciated as I'm mostly used to MS sql and we just switch to snowflake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the "created_date" is stored as a timestamp or datetime (synonyms), then you just need to remove the single quotes from around the created_date column name and change "to_char" to use the "monthname" function:

```
select date_part(year, created_date) as year,
       date_part(month, created_date) as month,
       monthname(created_date) as month_name,
       user_name,
       product
 from user_table
```